# Docker Image .net 6

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and I have created a Dockerfile

**FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0

USER root

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "EventRestProject.dll"]**

But I am not able to build it. Can someone point out where I am going wrong.

> docker build -t image5 .
> [+] Building 8.2s (7/8)
> => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                          0.0s
> => => transferring dockerfile: 324B                                                                                          0.0s
> => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                              0.0s
> => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0                                                          0.0s
> => [base 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0                                                                       0.0s
> => ERROR FROM docker.io/library/build:latest                                                                                 8.1s
> => => resolve docker.io/library/build:latest                                                                                 8.1s
> => CACHED [base 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                            0.0s
> => [auth] library/build:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                  0.0s

---

> FROM docker.io/library/build:latest:

### failed to load cache key: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

If I change the Dockerfile a bit, it is able to build but not run.

**FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

USER root

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ .    <----- Changed Part 

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "EventRestProject.dll"]**

Terminal:

> EventRestProject> docker build -t image5 .
> [+] Building 0.2s (8/8) FINISHED
> => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                        0.0s
> => => transferring dockerfile: 309B                                                                                          0.0s
> => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                             0.0s
> => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0                                                          0.0s
> => [1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0                                                                            0.0s
> => [internal] load build context                                                                                             0.0s
> => => transferring context: 420B                                                                                             0.0s
> => CACHED [2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                 0.0s
> => [3/3] COPY ./ .                                                                                                           0.0s
> => exporting to image                                                                                                        0.0s
> => => exporting layers                                                                                                       0.0s
> => => writing image sha256:f2cc9b8065ceaf18cdfcd6b56e8702f50c1e27dc5832eb2b84f8b9b74a559cf2                                  0.0s
> => => naming to docker.io/library/image5

> EventRestProject> docker run -p 8080:80 image4
> Unable to find image 'image4:latest' locally
> docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for image4, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

Comment: docker build -t image5 . is your build command and you trying to run image4

Answer (score 1):

The first image cannot be built because you are trying to use a reference that doesn't exist:

```
COPY --from=build /app .
```

Copying using the `from` command expects an earlier image build as part of a multistage docker file. The following example would work as it is creating an image named `builder` that can then be referenced later on as a source to copy from:

```
FROM alpine AS builder

RUN mkdir /app

FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /app .

ENTRYPOINT ['echo nothing']
```

That is the reason your second build is working. There you copy directly from the local directory into the image:

```
COPY ./ .
```

Your run error is resulting from the fact, that `image4` does not exist, since you are building `image5` as per your output:

```
docker build -t image5 .
```